# move a listview over imagerView

Tags: android, listview, imageview

How can I move a listView like this?

[image]

[image]

I added the listview and imageview , but I do not know how the move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/). You should use Recyclerview.